# System.IO.Directory.GetFiles returns different result than Windows XP Search Companion

Tags: windows, search, file-io, .net

I am using this statement to find all files recursively:

```
fileNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*",
    System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

The total number of files that are found is sgnificantly lower than wehen using Windows XP Search Companion. This is not caused by hidden files, I checked that. It looks like some directories with a deep nesting level are skipped by GetFiles, but not by Windows Search Companion. GetFiles counts the same number of files as "dir /s" in a command prompt. Anyone have a clue?

Thanks,
Neeva

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search Companion looks inside ZIP files.  Do you have any of those in the directory tree?

Answer (score 1):

Can you confirm that there is no exception thrown?

Particularly, [PathTooLongException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.pathtoolongexception.aspx)?

```
try {
    fileNames = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*",
        System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories);

} catch (System.IOPathTooLongException) {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Fail("Some path is too long to be processed.");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

System files?

What's the result of:

```
dir/s/as  
dir/s/ah
```

The search companion could have filters on, have you checked that?

And can you publish the search result?